# Can't vertically align the label with respect to the Checkbox

Tags: html, css, forms

Check this page first http://bbbread.com/us/

On bottom left of this page there is a gear logo & once clicked, that opens the modal popup showing the **Login** area.

I  always struggle  with form css (never got the hang of it) but this one is really tough. I’ve tried & tried but I can’t vertically align the ***Remember Me*** text and the radio button.

I've tried adding margin, padding, line-height, etc. but the radio button refuses to align itself vertically with the text.

Can any one help me with this one?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: We'd need to see the actual HTML/CSS to offer a proper solution. Can you make JSFiddle or Codepen demo?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem **and include valid code to reproduce it in the question itself**. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @Paulie_D While fiddles are handy, the question itself must contain the (relevant) code, not some random site somewhere on the web.

Comment: You are going to need to put the last elements in some sort of div container so you can arrange each element the way you want. Currently you can't vertically align anything because there is nothing to reference it.

Answer (score 3):

add this to your css

```
.forgetmenot-label input[type="checkbox"] {
            display: inline-block;
            width: auto;
            margin: 0px 5px;
            vertical-align: text-top;
           }
```

Comment: YOU TOTALLY ROCK!!!!

Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: This is Cooooooool but the position of text cam right side :(

Comment: I could careless that the radio box is on the right of the text now. LOL

I just hate form css.  I can never get the hang of it.

Comment: "vertical-align: text-top;" - I will never forget this now!!!